# Create route for root path, '/', with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to set a RestPath for root, '/', but its not allowing me to. Its saying `RestPath '/' on Type 'MainTasks' is not Valid`

Is there a way to allow this? I'd like to provide a resource from the root.

```
[Route("/", "GET")]
public class MainTasks : IReturn<MainTasksResponse>
{
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only match on the Route `/` Path in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) with a [FallbackRoute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fallback-route), e.g:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class Fallback
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

This uses a wildcard to handle every unmatched route (inc. /foo/bar). Only 1 fallback route is allowed.

There are also a few other ways to handle the default root path /:

1. Change the `EndpointHostConfig.DefaultRedirectPath` to redirect to the service you wish to use
2. Add a `default.cshtml` Razor or Markdown View or static `default.htm` (for HTML requests)
3. Register a `EndpointHostConfig.RawHttpHandlers` - This is the first handler looked at in [ServiceStack's Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations).
4. Register a `IAppHost.CatchAllHandlers` - This gets called for **un-matched** requests.
5. Handle the request in a [Global Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll have to be exposing everything from "/api".

Comment: Creating default.htm redirects to http://localhost/default.htm. Is there a way to serve it from http://localhost directly?

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me.  I just added the RawHttpHandler and rewrote the request path.  Worked like a champ.  (This is found in my AppHost's Configure function.)

```
var conf = new EndpointHostConfig();
{
    DefaultRedirectPath = "/foo",
    AllowFileExtensions = { { "eot" }, { "svg" }, { "ttf" }, { "woff" } },
};

conf.RawHttpHandlers.Add(r =>
{
    if (r.RawUrl == "/")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(conf.DefaultRedirectPath);
    }

    return null;
});

this.SetConfig(conf);
```

Comment: That is indeed awesome, thanks! I am using it to redirect '/' to an entire different Url (the servicestack app runs purely as a faceless api endpoint & '/' redirects to the API documentation site now) using '[...]HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://somesite.com/api", true);[...]'.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do this and found Christopher Davies method to no longer work in the latest service stack for a self hosted service.  The following on my service that takes no parameters worked.

[FallbackRoute("/")]