# ServiceStack - Redirecting at root based on query params

Tags: servicestack, single-page-application

<strike>I've got a Fallback DTO that looks like the following:</strike>

```csh
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")]
public class Fallback
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my Service I would like to redirect to an HTML5 compliant URL, and this is what I've tried:

```csh
public object Get(Fallback fallback)
{
    return this.Redirect("/#!/" + fallback.Path);
}
```

It is working all fine and dandy, except for the fact that query parameters are not passed along with the path. Using `Request.QueryString` does not work as no matter what I do it is empty. Here's what my current (non-working) solution looks like:

```csh
public object Get(Fallback fallback)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("?");
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Request.QueryString)
    {
        sb.Append(item.Key).Append("=").Append(item.Value).Append("&");
    }
    var s = "/#!/" + fallback.Path + sb.ToString();
    return this.Redirect(s);
}
```

**TL;DR:** I want to pass on query strings along with fallback path.

**EDIT:** It turns out I had two problems; now going to `mysite.com/url/that/does/not/exist?random=param` correctly redirects the request to `mysite.com/#!/url/that/does/not/exist?random=param&` after I changed the above loop to:

```csh
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString)
{
    sb.Append(key).Append("=").Append(Request.QueryString[key]).Append("&");
}
```

*But* the fallback is still not being called at root, meaning `mysite.com/?random=param` won't trigger anything.

In essence, what I want to do is to have ServiceStack look for query strings at root, e.g., `mysite.com/?key=value`, apply some logic and then fire off a redirect. The purpose of this is in order for crawler bots to be able to query the site with a `_escaped_fragment_` parameter and then be presented with an HTML snapshot prepared by a server. This is in order for the bots to be able to index single-page applications ([more on this](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)).

I'm thinking perhaps the FallbackRoute function won't cover this and I need to resort to overriding the `CatchAllHandler`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019670/722871).

First create an `EndpointHostConfig` object in your `AppHost`:

```csh
var config = new EndpointHostConfig
{
    ...
};
```

Then, add a `RawHttpHandler`:

```csh
config.RawHttpHandlers.Add(r =>
{
    var crawl = r.QueryString["_escaped_fragment_"];
    if (crawl != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/location_of_snapshots/" + crawl);
    }
    return null;
});
```

Going to `mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=home?key=value` will fire off a redirection to `mysite.com/location_of_snapshots/home?key=value`, which should satisfy the AJAX crawling bots.

**N.B.** It's possible some logic needs to be applied to the redirection to ensure that there won't be double forward slashes. I have yet to test that.